# highlight strings from one df to another df

Tags: ruby, string

I have a txt file like below. As an example it has 6 rows. each raw have a string or multiple strings. for example the first row has only one string but the second one has two (they are separated with a comma). I also put the number of rows to make the example clear

```
1 P41182
2 P41152,Q9UQL6
3 P41172
4 Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9
5 Q15021,TQ9472 
6 Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3
```

I have another text which looks like below. The same structure. for example the first row has only one string but the second has two

```
1 P41182
2 P41152,Q9UYIU
3 P41172
4 Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT
5 P30561
6 Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3
7 HT8971
8 HLI872
```

I want to know the index of some of the strings from the second data that are similar to the first data. There are some roles as follows:

If only 1 string is in the first txt and matched to second txt, **I don't want to know the index.** If there is more than one string in first txt and one of them or some of them are similar to the second txt file, then I want to know the index of them for example the output should look like the following
df3

```
1 P41182
2 P41152_2_1,Q9UYIU
3 P41172
4 Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT
5 P30561
6 Q15021_5_1_6_1,Q9BPX3_6_2,Q15003_6_3,O95347_6_4,Q9NTJ3_6_5
7 HT8971
8 HLI872
```

The first string of second data is similar to a string of first data with only 1 member (strings in each element are separated by a comma) so I leave it as it is and I don't want the index.

The second string in second txt file is similar to the second row and first string of that row in the first txt file, so it gets 2_1

The sixth string in second txt is similar to the fifth row and first one of first txt and also it is similar to the sixth row and first string of the first txt file so it gets 5_1 and 6_1

etc etc .

Comment: I think the last one didn't turn out okay as something happened with the length.

Comment: yes, I will run it.  Please give me some time.

Comment: I found that in one case, there are more than one match.  What should we do for those cases?

Comment: I am utterly mystified by this question. Am I the only reader who doesn't know what a "df" is? Is this a Rails question? If so, you need a Rails tag.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland you are right, it was generally a R question but since it is a text mining, I try to solve it by ruby. I modified the question to be understandable , is it now ok ?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know what "df" means. Can the `df`'s be regarded as arrays whose elements are read from a file?  Is the first element of the first df `"# 1 P41182"`, `"1 P41182"` or `"P41182"`?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland df is a set of strings together which consists of many elements for example df1 first row has one element P41182 , row 2 has two elements P41152 and Q9UQL6 . is it clear now ?

Comment: You need to define the data in terms of Ruby objects. You say "'df' is a set of strings". I don't think you mean an instance of the class `Set`. Do you mean arrays of strings, lines in file, or what? Also, you refer to "'df1' first row". The only Ruby object that has rows are instances of the class `Matrix`. If the strings are elements of an array or lines in a file, use the terms "element" or "line". Also, "similar" requires a definition. Be precise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following ruby code should work: 
Make sure you have df1.txt and df2.txt as comma separated. You will have the output in df3.txt. Please see the sample txt files below.

```
df1_hash = {}
df1_term_positions_hash = Hash.new([])
File.readlines("df1.txt").each_with_index do |line, i|
    df1_hash[i+1] = line.strip.split(",")
    for x in line.strip.split(",")
        df1_term_positions_hash[x] += [i+1]
    end
end

df2_hash = {}
File.readlines("df2.txt").each_with_index do |line, i|
    df2_hash[i+1] = line.strip.split(",")
end

df2_size = df2_hash.size
df3_hash = {}
for i in (1..df2_size)
    df3_hash[i] = df2_hash[i].each_with_index.map do |term, intermediate_index|
        number_of_repetitions = df1_term_positions_hash[term].size      
        updated_term = term.dup
        df1_term_positions_hash[term].each_with_index do |repetition_position, index|
            if (df1_hash[repetition_position].size <= 1 rescue true )
                updated_term = term


            else
                additional_tail = "#{repetition_position}_#{df1_hash[repetition_position].index(term)+1}"               
                updated_term = updated_term + "_" + additional_tail
            end
        end
        updated_term
    end

end

File.open("df3.txt", "w") do |file|
    for i in (1..df2_size)
        file.puts df3_hash[i].join(",")
    end
end
```

## df1.txt

```
P41182
P41152,Q9UQL6
P41172
Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9
Q15021,TQ9472 
Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3
```

## df2.txt

```
P41182
P41152,Q9UYIU
P41172
Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT
P30561
Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3
HT8971
HLI872
```

## output in df3.txt

```
P41182
P41152_2_1,Q9UYIU
P41172
Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT
P30561
Q15021_5_1_6_1,Q9BPX3_6_2,Q15003_6_3,O95347_6_4,Q9NTJ3_6_5
HT8971
HLI872
```

sorry for little messy code, but it works.
Hope it helps : )

Comment: @nik can you please check and let me know if its ok?

Comment: you can .. only if you think the answer is appropriate and working : ).

Comment: @nik updated the code. Can you please remove extra (conversational) comments from this answer. Feels redundant. Lets not load SO with it.

Comment: Plotting is definitely possible in ruby, and there are many libraries (gems) for it. I personally use https://github.com/topfunky/gruff. But, I guess it wouldn't be as beautiful as in R. I suggest you use python or R for plotting.

Comment: I know .. but I use ruby and python much more than I do Java. I personally, dont like it much - because it's just too verbose and i cant handle it!

Answer (score 2):

I've assumed the data can be represented by arrays of strings.

```
arr1 = ["P41182", "P41152,Q9UQL6", "P41172", "Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9",
        "Q15021,TQ9472", "Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3"]
arr2 = ["P41182", "P41152,Q9UYIU", "P41172", "Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT", "P30561",
        "Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3", "HT8971", "HLI872"] 

h = arr1.each.with_index(1).with_object({}) do |(s1,i),h|
  next unless s1.include?(',')
  s1.split(',').each.with_index(1) { |s2,j| (h[s2] ||= '') << "_#{i}_#{j}" }
end
  #=> {"P41152"=>"_2_1", "Q9UQL6"=>"_2_2", "Q92793"=>"_4_1", "Q09472"=>"_4_2",
  #    "Q9Y6Q9"=>"_4_3", "Q15021"=>"_5_1_6_1", "TQ9472"=>"_5_2", "Q9BPX3"=>"_6_2",
  #    "Q15003"=>"_6_3", "O95347"=>"_6_4", "Q9NTJ3"=>"_6_5"} 

arr2.map {|s1| s1.split(',').map { |s2| h.key?(s2) ? "%s%s" % [s2, h[s2]] : s2 }.join(',')}
  #=> ["P41182", "P41152_2_1,Q9UYIU", "P41172", "Q9IO93,Q9Y6IT", "P30561",
  #    "Q15021_5_1_6_1,Q9BPX3_6_2,Q15003_6_3,O95347_6_4,Q9NTJ3_6_5", "HT8971", "HLI872"]
```

Comment: I made it now very clear !!! I hope that now you can follow my question

Comment: If my answer is correct there is nothing to explain. If, not, why should `P41152` be `P41152_2_1`, as given in your question?

Comment: I did an edit, but am still not sure if I understand the question completely. Suppose `arr1 = [ "abc", "def,abc", "ghi"]` and `arr2 = ["abc", "ghi"]`. Should the answer be `["abc_2_2", "ghi"]` (my current answer) or `["abc_1_1_2_2", "ghi"]`?

Comment: let me explain. in your example, you have abc, def, abc,ghi. all of them are in one line . the second array is abc, ghi and again in one line. so the first things is that we check for abc, we see we have in array 1 which consists of 4 elements, we have two abc, one is the first element and one is the third element , so the answer for it will be abc_1_1_1_3 , the second one is ghi and we have a similar element in array 1 and that array has 4 elements so the role is OK and it will also get the index ghi_1_4  . is it clear now ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "...you have `abc`, `def`, `abc,ghi`. All of them are in one line". Arrays don't have the concept of lines. If I were to read your first file into an array, that array would be `arr1 #=> ["P41182", 
"P41152,Q9UQL6", "P41172", "Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9", "Q15021,TQ9472", "Q15021,Q9BPX3,Q15003,O95347,Q9NTJ3"]`. Simlarly, in my example, the (three) elements of `arr1` correspond to the (three) lines of the file that I've read into `arr1`.  Therefore, the first line of the file wold be `"abc"`, the second line, `"def,abc"` and the third, `"ghi"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland awesome answer. Really liked how you could manage how you could do it in so less number of lines.

Comment: Thanks, @Harsh. It just takes practice.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes I can truely see that from you profile. #respect : )

Comment: @Cary Swoveland thanks I accepted the other answer because i understand it better. otherwise your answer is much shorter and probably more efficient ! however thanks for your time